# How to get array value in html using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```html
<section id="secProducts" class="container">
        <div id="CART_TEMPLATE" style="display:none">
              <figure>
                <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img02" class="img-responsive" height="80" width="80" />
                     <figcaption>
                         <p>Product Name:</p>
                          <p class="productname"></p>
                          <label for="quant">Enter Quantity:</label>
                     <input type="number" id="quant" name="quant[]" min="1" > 
                   </figcaption>
             </figure>
         /* Try to get Value of input from name="quant[]" .But Unable to get document.getElementsByName("quant[0]").value; ? */
      </div>
  </section>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function socialSharing()
{
    alert("Hi:");
    var fun1=document.getElementsByName("quant[0]").value;
    alert(fun1);
    var fun2=document.getElementsByName("quant[1]").value;
    alert(fun2);
    alert(bar2);    
}
```

In Html, there is an array of Product Details. It displays all products. But I'm trying to get quantity details with `var fun1=document.getElementsByName("quant[0]").value;` which returns undefined.

Comment: What are you trying to get with quant[0] and quant[1] ? From your html it seems that you have only one input (type number) and its name is quant[]. Also getElementsByName is going to return not only one but an array of elements (because multiple elements can have the same name) so I would rather do something like this : ```var fun1=document.getElementsByName("quant[]")[0].value;```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value of the input elements using the following code:

```
var fun1 = document.getElementsByName("quant[0]")[0].value;
var fun2 = document.getElementsByName("quant[1]")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small reproduction for the problem: [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/manuel3108/pen/gOjEYBp)

The main point as described in other answers, is that getElementsByName() can return multiple elements, compared to getElementById()

```js
// instead of this
var fun1 = document.getElementsByName("quant[0]").value;

// get the first element of the returned result and get this value
var fun1 = document.getElementsByName("quant[0]")[0].value;
```

```js
function socialSharing()
{
    var fun1=document.getElementsByName("quant[0]")[0].value;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "Detected quantity " + fun1 + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<section id="secProducts" class="container">
  <div id="CART_TEMPLATE" >
    <figure>
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="img02" class="img-responsive" height="80" width="80" />
      <figcaption>
        <p>Product Name:</p>
        <p class="productname"></p>
        <label for="quant">Enter Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" id="quant" name="quant[0]" min="1" onkeyup="socialSharing()">
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</section>
  
<div id="results"></div>
```

In order to show that the code above works, I have added a new div, where each key press handled by the `onkeyup` event of the input field, will write down the current value of the input field